# Using a companion object in my Fragment to save a static object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a NavHostFragment inside a Fragment.
In the NavHost, there is a Fragment navigation with various steps (10 steps) to setup an CustomObject. At the end of the 10 steps, the object (converted to JSON) will be sended to a webservice.

I use a companion object including a variable for my CustomObject in my Fragment like this :

```
class MyFragment{
 companion object{
        var customObject: CustomObject = CustomObject()
    }
}
```

After each step in my differents Fragments, I fill my object like this :

```
MyFragment.customObject.variable1 = value1
MyFragment.customObject.variable2 = value2
...
```

I don't know if I'm clear : I have a static object in a Fragment, used in various Fragments.
I would like to know if it's a good practice to do that.

I can send my variables from a Fragment to an other Fragment using args (or safe-args) with the navigation component but for 10 steps it would be repetitive and useless, no ?

What do you do in this common kind of case (for example, on a registration steps, asking on each screen the name, age, adress,... and at the last screen getting an object with all these informations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach you described is not good and you should be better with https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

If you do not want/plan to go with view models in the first place (and shared activity view model in the first place, aka `activityViewModels`), I'd still suggest to avoid using companions (statics) - may be you could keep everything in arguments while navigating from one to another (fragment arguments).

PS.: the reason why statics isn't going to work is what happens when your app resumes from sleep. The whatever state you put into statics has a good chance to be lost.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer view models approach but if you are using old architecture then I'll go for local database for this kind of solution.
My suggestion for you is to use MVVM because it make things much easier.